# Using nuxt google optimize module with google optimize

Tags: vue.js, optimization, nuxt.js

Could anyone give me advice on how to link the above? I’ve set up a simple test as in the nuxt google optimize example but having trouble linking the variables I’ve set to the variables set in google optimize.

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: I’ve set up variables in my nuxt module but not sure how they link to the variables you set up in google optimize?